# Fink not showing package python24

Tags: macos, fink

Just to be clear: I know nothing about fink.

I just installed fink on Snow Leopard, from cvs. If I run fink list, only python25 and python26 are shown. Strangely enough I have ./fink/10.4/stable/main/finkinfo/languages/python24.info. as well as python25.info and python26.info in the same path. I don't understand how to make python24 available as well.

Any hints ?

Thank you!

Comment: would that make any difference to the way the program operates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to Fink, as in my experience things tend to work better and more packages are available in MacPorts.

Looking at [this Fink page for its Python 2.4 package](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/python24), it doesn't appear to be available for 10.6.

MacPorts has these versions of Python available for 10.6:

```
python21                       @2.1.3          lang/python21
python22                       @2.2.3          lang/python22
python23                       @2.3.7          lang/python23
python24                       @2.4.6          lang/python24
python25                       @2.5.4          lang/python25
python26                       @2.6.2          lang/python26
python30                       @3.0.1          lang/python30
python31                       @3.1            lang/python31
```

Comment: fact is that nothing is tecchnically available for 10.6, it has not been targeted yet apparently.

Comment: went for macports, much better. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it as 32-bit or 64-bit? From what I understand, the number of packages that are currently available in the 64-bit tree is much smaller than those in the 32-bit.